# In microsoft SRS how do I group rows?

Tags: reporting-services

In Microsoft SRS I want to create custom groups for Rows.  What I want to do is to take the values by time but display only three bands, Morning afternoon and night.  So by using the time I want to group the rows.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest adding extra columns to the SQL. Use a  `CASE` statement so that times falling in the range of 00:01 to 11:59 are given the literal value of `Morning`. Values 12:00 to 17:00 `Afternoon` etc.  Then use these to group!

Comment: For columns read column ... you only need the one extra column!

Comment: Thanks, perfect suggestion!  Did, this, works perfectly!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1688277/marc-l could you mark my answer below as a solution your problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an extra column to the SQL. Use a CASE statement so that times falling in the range of 00:01 to 11:59 are given the literal value of "Morning". Values 12:00 to 17:00 "Afternoon" and 17:01 - 23:59 as "Evening". Then use this column to group the data.